# Incrementing array index inline

Tags: c

I am new to C. Sorry for such a basic question.

```
int ArrayIndex = 0;
int intArray[ArrayIndex++] = somevalue;
```

I have read a book that says *when exactly postfix increment/decrement is performed is not a simple question to answer*. The book also says vaguely about a concept called `sequence points` to answer the question. It says updating the value[incrementing/decrementing] will take place between the previous and next sequence point. The example for such a sequence point is end of an expression statement.

My question is, will the above code snippet always assign `some value` to array index zero and increment ArrayIndex, in all compilers/platforms? Is there a chance that ArrayIndex is incremented first and then somevalue is assigned to intArry[1];?

Can anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, will the above code snippet always assign some value
>   to array index zero and increment ArrayIndex, in all
>   compilers/platforms?

Answer: Yes

> Is there a chance that ArrayIndex is incremented first and then
>   somevalue is assigned to intArry[1];?

Answer: If you use

```
int intArray[++ArrayIndex] = somevalue;
```

this will increment `ArrayIndex` and then assign value to array index 1

Answer (score 2):

`++ArrayIndex` **increments** `ArrayIndex` and evaluates to the new value of `ArrayIndex`.

`ArrayIndex++` **evaluates to the old value** of `ArrayIndex`, and increments `ArrayIndex`.

This should answer your question. (Hint: the answer is yes).

Comment: Naming conventions are quite irrelevant here to say the least.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze You're right. As long as he's consistent this shouldn't bother.

Comment: It's not that. First, naming conventions weren't asked about. Second, they are subjective or specific to the team/project. Third, the question does not have low readability (like the poorly formatted long code you've seen in some other questions) due to the naming convention chosen. So, there's not a single objective reason to point at it at all.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Sometimes it doesn't hurt if you add additional notes/improvements even if they were not asked. But, as I said before, I agree with you in this case.. I shouldn't have mentioned it and that's why I edited my answer and removed it.

Comment: Sometimes yes, I agree, but not this time.